# If $A=\begin{pmatrix}0.3&b&c\\l&m&n\\0&p&q\end{pmatrix}$ be an orthogonal matrix then find possible values of $mq-np$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, orthogonality

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}0.3&b&c\\l&m&n\\0&p&q\end{pmatrix}$ be an orthogonal matrix then find possible values of $mq-np$

My Attempt:

Since $AA^T=I$

I got the following equations

$b^2+c^2=0.91$

$l^2+m^2+n^2=1$

$p^2+q^2=1$

$0.3l+mb+nc=0$

$bp+cq=0$

$pm+nq=0$

But I am unable to solve further

Comment: have you tried calculating $\det\big(A\big)$?  Also you know the modulus of $l$...

Comment: @user8675309 $|A|=0.3(mq-np)+l(pc-bq)=\pm 1$. But after this what to do

Comment: again you know the modulus of $l$ so pick its positive value (then re-run with its negative value).   Explicitly compute $A^TA = I$ if you need to.  The orthonormal columns are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have slightly more information available to us than just orthonormality of the rows.  We have it for the columns too.  This tells us that $\ell^2=0.91$, so $\ell=\pm \sqrt{0.91}$.  The $0$ in the bottom left also helps us out with the orthogonality of the columns, because if $(a,b,0)$ is orthogonal to $(x,y,z)$, then (from 2 dimensional considerations) $(x,y)$ is proportional to $(b,-a)$.  This means we can find $\alpha, \beta$ such that $(b,m)=\alpha(\ell,-0.3)$ and $(c,n)=\beta(\ell,-0.3)$.  Doing a similar thing with the rows means that we can find $\gamma$ such that our matrix is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0.3  & -\alpha\ell  & -\beta\ell \\
                  \ell & 0.3\alpha    & 0.3 \beta \\
                  0    &  \gamma \beta & -\gamma\alpha \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that all we have used to get this is that the first column is orthogonal to the others, and the last row is orthogonal to the others.

From the fact that the first row and the first column are both of length $1$, we get $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$.  From the fact that the last row is of length $1$, we get $1=\gamma^2(\alpha^2+\beta^2)=\gamma^2$.  Finally, $mq-np=-0.3\gamma(\alpha^2+\beta^2)=-0.3\gamma=\pm 0.3$.

---

This actually generalizes.  We don't need that the bottom left corner is $0$, although computing things by hand would be much harder in that case.  Instead, we can use Cramer's rule (in the following form):

$$M\operatorname{adj}(M)=\det(M)I$$

where the $(i,j)$ entry if $\operatorname{adj}(M)$ is $(-1)^{i+j}$ times the determinant of $M$ if we cross out the ith column and jth row.

Now, since $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, the condition $A^TA=I$ means that $\det(A)=\pm 1$.  Then $A=(A^{-1})^T=\pm \operatorname{adj}(A)^T$.  Now, simply look at the (1,1) entry of each side.